# How to escape '--' in hibernate createSqlQuery?

Tags: hibernate, native-sql

The code is as follow:

```java
sql = " select '--', staff_no from staff where staff_no = ?";
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();               
Query sqlQuery2 = session2.createSQLQuery(sql);             
sqlQuery2.setParameter(0, "04415");  //error in this line
```

When run, error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond
> number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal
> parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

is thrown, I know this is caused by the '--' in sql string, hibernate interpret it as sql comment,

I try to use

```
"select '\\-\\-', staff_no from ...."
```

this can run successfully, but the output becomes \-\-, but what I want is -- in output.

So how to escape the '--' in hibernate `createSqlQuery`?

The problem is caused by the '--' in select clause, if I run

```
sql = " select '-', staff_no from staff where staff_no = ?";
```

no problem is found.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

As your error message stated:

> Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

try to use this:

```java
sql = " select \"--\", staff_no from staff where staff_no = ?1";
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();               
Query sqlQuery2 = session2.createSQLQuery(sql);             
sqlQuery2.setParameter(1, "04415");
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api):

> JPQL-style positional parameters are declared using a question mark followed by an ordinal - `?1`, `?2`. *The ordinals start with 1*. Just like with named parameters, positional parameters can also appear multiple times in a query.

Comment: No, this does not solve the problem, still the same error. Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2

Comment: Try to use `" select \"--\", staff_no from staff where staff_no = ?1"` as it stated [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find any method, but use a workaround as follow can work:

```
sql = " select replace ('- -', ' ', ''), staff_no from staff where staff_no = ?";
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();               
Query sqlQuery2 = session2.createSQLQuery(sql);             
sqlQuery2.setParameter(0, "04415");
```